# Is it possible to get the bytecode of an already deployed contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, bytecode

Is it possible to get the bytecode of an already deployed contract
from another contract?

Example: get bytecode of contract A using contract B in Solidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using assembly, you can get the code of any contract. The code below do just that (from the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html#example)

```
function at(address _addr) public view returns (bytes o_code) {
        assembly {
            // retrieve the size of the code, this needs assembly
            let size := extcodesize(_addr)
            // allocate output byte array - this could also be done without assembly
            // by using o_code = new bytes(size)
            o_code := mload(0x40)
            // new "memory end" including padding
            mstore(0x40, add(o_code, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
            // store length in memory
            mstore(o_code, size)
            // actually retrieve the code, this needs assembly
            extcodecopy(_addr, add(o_code, 0x20), 0, size)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is now possible to read the code of another contract using both plain Solidity and assembly (Yul).

### Plain Solidity

As per the docs on [Members of Address Types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types)

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract GetCode {
    function at(address _addr) public view returns (bytes memory o_code) {
        return _addr.code;
    }
}
```

### Assembly

Example taken from the docs:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

library GetCode {
    function at(address _addr) public view returns (bytes memory o_code) {
        assembly {
            // retrieve the size of the code
            let size := extcodesize(_addr)
            // allocate output byte array
            // by using o_code = new bytes(size)
            o_code := mload(0x40)
            // new "memory end" including padding
            mstore(0x40, add(o_code, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
            // store length in memory
            mstore(o_code, size)
            // actually retrieve the code, this needs assembly
            extcodecopy(_addr, add(o_code, 0x20), 0, size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also work:

`> eth.getCode("CONTRACT ADDRESS")`

`"0x60806040526004361061..."`

After getting the Byte code, remove the "0x" at the beginning and then use this Solidity decompiler, https://ethervm.io/decompile, to decompile the bytecode.