# Does `<address>.code` return code for precompiles?

Tags: solidity, precompiled-contracts

As shown [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/109393/24693), is is possible to read the code of a contract using plain Solidity by using the `.code` member of the address type:

```
contract GetCode {
    function at(address _addr) public view returns (bytes memory o_code) {
        return _addr.code;
    }
}
```

Does this return any code for precompiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *no* - The `.code` member does not return the code for precompiled addresses.

Let's take the following examples:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.18;

contract Foo {
    function getCode1() external view returns (bytes memory) {
        address addr1 = address(1);
        return addr1.code;
    }

    function getCode2() external view returns (bytes memory) {
        address addr2 = address(2);
        return addr2.code;
    }
}
```

Calling either `getCode1` or `getCode2` returns a zero bytes array.

For more information about precompiles, see this other Q&A here on StackExchange: [List of pre-compiled contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15479/24693).